# Polymer paper-tabs selection not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, polymer, web-component

While developing my personal website with Polymer (v1.0+), by modifying a copy of the PSK (Polymer Starter Kit), I'm running into problems with my `selected` attribute when trying to make use of Polymer's `dom-repeat` templates for my navigation menus with an array of my routes and their attributes.

The repeating behavior works, the routing works, and (most of) the data works as expected, but the selection is not recognized and/or displayed correctly, translating into the selected menu item not being visually "selected" (not having the fancy selection effects).

Although I understand a bit of HTML, CSS, and JS, I'm still quite new to web-development, so this is probably some understanding about data-binding or JS that I'm still missing.

So here are the questions:
**Why does the dynamic version of the code not work? And how can I fix it?**

---

## Here is what I have:

**app.js:**

```
(function (document) {
  'use strict';

  var app = document.querySelector('#app');

  app.baseUrl = '/';

  /*
   * About 100 lines of unrelated "...", about 60 taken from PSK
   */

  app.routeMap = [
    {name: "home", text: "Home", icon: "home", url: app.baseUrl},
    {name: "about", text: "About", icon: "face", url: app.baseUrl + "about"},
    {name: "users", text: "Users", icon: "info", url: app.baseUrl + "users"},
    {name: "contact", text: "Contact", icon: "mail", url: app.baseUrl + "contact"}
  ];

})(document);
```

---

**HTML that works:**

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">

  <!-- ... -->

  <paper-tabs attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
    <paper-tab data-route="home">
      <a href="{{baseUrl}}">
        <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
    </paper-tab>
    <paper-tab data-route="about">
      <a href="{{baseUrl}}about">
        <iron-icon icon="face"></iron-icon>
        <span>About</span>
      </a>
    </paper-tab>
  </paper-tabs>
</template>
```

---

**HTML that *doesn't* work:** <sub><sup>(but that I'm trying to make work)</sup></sub>

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">

  <!-- ... -->

  <paper-tabs attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{routeMap}}">
      <paper-tab data-route="{{item.name}}">
        <a href="{{item.url}}">
          <iron-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"></iron-icon>
          <span>{{item.text}}</span>
        </a>
      </paper-tab>
    </template>
  </paper-tabs>
</template>
```

Comment: What you get on html output? It generates links? Maybe you need to create your own component and in it generate `<paper-tabs>` after announce `routeMap` in this component.

Comment: @Dmitry It generates everything as expected (I think). The items are there; the text, icons and links are correct; the styling seems to be correct; everything... Only the selection is not working. --- As for making my own component, I don't see why it would have an effect, considering the data is being accessed without any problem. Apparently, it's the selection that is not matching between `attr-for-selected` from the array and `selected=[[route]]` from the PSK's original code. Both should be an equal `"about"` when on the about page, for example, so that would be selected; but they aren't(?)

Comment: Try to change `data-route` attribute  from `<paper-tab>` to `a`, because in all example it set in anchor tag.  And also check in console source of your page, you should see if correctly formed your list with `<paper-tab>` because in Polymer to binding to attribute needs this `data-route$=`

Comment: Moving `data-route` to anchor tag has no effect; AFAIK because `data-route` (or whatever the "`attr-name`" is set) is expected to be present as the children of the element with `attr-for-selected="attr-name"` (I can be wrong...). And in the examples/sources from polymer, it just so happens that they used `a`s as children instead of other elements (with `a`s within), like I'm doing --- As for using `$=` instead of `=`, **you are absolutely right!** `<paper-tab data-route$="{{item.name}}">` got things working like a charm! Please post as answer so I can give you some well-deserved rep-candy! =)

Comment: You are welcome! Always happy to help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer binding to element attribute requires such a record  `data-route$=name of route`